# How to use different CSS files for different page with react js

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am building my first react app and i have a problem ! I am trying to use different css files for different Route. But when i import a second css file(loginpage.css), the first page (homepage) is changing !

How can i use a css file by page ?

Thanks you for your help !

```js
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import HomePage  from './components/pages/HomePage';
import LoginPage from './components/pages/LoginPage';
import DashboardPage from './components/pages/DashboardPage';
import SignupPage from './components/pages/SignupPage';
import ConfirmationPage from './components/pages/ConfirmationPage';
import UserRoute from './components/routes/UserRoute';
import GuestRoute from './components/routes/GuestRoute';
import './static/stylesheets/default.css';
import './static/stylesheets/pandoc-code-highlight.css';
import styles from './static/stylesheets/homepage.css';
import styles1 from './static/stylesheets/loginpage.css';


const App = ({ location }) => (
 <div classname="">
  <div classname={styles}>
   <Route location={location} path="/" exact component={HomePage} />
  </div>
        <div className={styles1.app}>
            <GuestRoute location={location} path="/login" exact component={LoginPage} />
        </div>
  <Route location={location} path="/confirmation/:token" exact component={ConfirmationPage} />
  <GuestRoute location={location} path="/signup" exact component={SignupPage} />
  <UserRoute location={location} path="/dashboard" exact component={DashboardPage} />
 </div>
);
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? What exactly do you mean by changing? What happens before you import the loginpage.css file and what happens after?

Comment: I think className should be accepting the name of a class, which should be a string, but not the name of the file that you are importing. To use a style, use style={style}. Also, I think you should be importing the login page style into the login page, not that page. Maybe the styles are getting overwritten.

Comment: Sorry my english is not perfect. i am french ! @theJuls when i import 'loginpage.css', it change my 'homepage' and css files are apply for the both page, and not one css file for a page !

Comment: @bprdev i tried to use style but it doesn't work, i want to use the css file 'homepage.css' for my homepage, and the same for loginpage. I tried to import in loginpage or homepage but it still the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using props:

```
const Front = (props) => {
    if(props.match.params.page === 'home'){
        require("./css/bootstrap.min.css");
        require("./css/style.css");
        require("./css/vendors.css");
        require("./css/custom.css");
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <Header />
            { props.match.params.page === 'home' ? <Login /> : null }

        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Include your `CSS` or `SCSS` file in specific component

Example:

```
// this is rule component which have rule scss file 
import './assets/css/rule.scss';
class Rules extends React.Component {

} 

// this is report which have report.scss file
import './assets/css/report.scss';
class Report extends React.Component {

}
```

Now its depend how you make structure of your component as for this example i kept all this scss file is `assets` folder.

Comment: Both imported style files will be bundle in one file.